# media="print" and .noprint { display: none; } is not working

Tags: html, css, printing

So I have

```
.noprint
{
display: none;
}
```

in a stylesheet print.css and

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/print.css" media="print"/>
```

in my webpage header.

I've added the class noprint to several div's and images but they still show up in the print preview of Google Chrome.

Any ideas?

Comment: This should work . Make sure you have specified the path for href of link tag properly.

Comment: Try just listing the elements you want to not be displayed when printing in your stylesheet.

Comment: Good stuff, worked great for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a markup error that prevented the div's with the .noprint class to inherit the attributes from the css markup file.